Filament Shield - Unable to disable/enable SelectColumn with respect to User's Permission
-How do I  Unable to disable/enable SelectColumn  in table, with respect to User's Permission via Filament Shield Plugin which uses Spatie/Roles-permission under the hood
Here is my code which is not working : (means, no matter what the permission is, field is always enabled)
SelectColumn::make('status')
    ->options(AppointmentStatus::class)
    ->disabled(fn() => auth()->user()->cannot('update')) //via AppointmentPolicy

But this works (Yeah, superadmin with permission can change and non-admin users cannot.)
SelectColumn::make('status')
    ->options(AppointmentStatus::class)         
    ->disabled(fn() => !auth()->user()->hasPermissionTo('update_appointment')) //checking with permission 

Please somebody help me know why first method not works via Policy. But Update/Edit option via Action working normally as per user's permission.
